# Geoprocessing/Clip fails in QGIS 2.18.3 for Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, clip, ubuntu

I am trying to obtain a clipping of a contour map into a polygon by using the command

```
Vector-> Geoprocessing tools -> Clip
```

in QGIS 2.18.13 freshly installed on Ubuntu 14.04.
I run the command on a contour lines layer whose files are within a directory since it is a DXF file (to be imported to autocad) and a shapefile (a polygon basically)

But when I run the command I get the message:

> "NameError: global name 'features' is not defined"

Is this error due to some coding glitch in the new release? What is the global name Features referring to?

Comment: Hi PolyGeo...I am not sure I understand why you edited my post. You took the word "regards" away. Why? I know it doens't add to my original question but I think showing respect and politeness towards the people who might read my question is important and makes this forum more human friendly.

Comment: Politeness also comes in the form of meeting social expectations. Here in GIS SE, it is polite to honor the "no chit-chat" charter, and curate a question that is direct and to the point. As a question in a database of questions, introdutions, thanks, closings, and signatures all just waste space on the server.

Comment: Hi Vince, thanks for your opinion. So from what you write, saying "Regards" is considered chit-chat...I didn't know or even imagine that...For me social expectations also means 'wasting' a few bits for the sake of making a cold forum like this (like any other virtual communications spaces, for that matter) more human. Anyway I am grateful for the other edits since I understand the aims of making the questions more readily answerable.

Comment: Have you tried converting the contours to shapefiles before attempting the clip? Might be a DXF issue.

Comment: Not sure how to do that, what's the way to do it? Within the .DXF directory there are 4 files and one of them is a .SHP file. On the other hand the layers panel just shows the name of the directory where this file is contained (and the directory name has the .DXF extension)

Comment: Can you add a list of all the files in the directory, and maybe the full error text from the Processing log file?

Comment: This is the list of all files: 
contour.dbf 4,9 kB
contour.prj 0 bytes
contour.shp 532,0 kB
contour.shx 1,9 Kb As for the full error text...here it is: Uncaught error while executing algorithm
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/core/GeoAlgorithm.py", line 203, in execute
       self.processAlgorithm(progress)
     File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/Clip.py", line 99, in processAlgorithm
       total = 100.0 / len(features) if len(features) > 0 else 1
   NameError: global name 'features' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug in version 2.18.13 of QGIS.
https://issues.qgis.org/issues/17248

Answer (score 0):

are your contour lines shapefiles *line* type? If so, you need to convert to polygon to clip another polygon; you should also ensure projections are the same on both shapes